# How to return numerical part of a string before underscore

Tags: python, pandas, regex

```
CC3309_EasdfewrfwerwxD2Svddserw10_2022
```

For the above string, how can I return `3309` when doing a str.replace in the dataframe cell in pandas.
I used this:

```
df['col_name'].str.replace(r'^CC([0-9]{2,})_', r'val_to_be_replaced with', regex = True)
```

The output should have `3309` in the `col_name`

Comment: what you want is unclear, please provide a clear input DataFrame and the matching expected output

Comment: `df['col_name'] = df['col_name'].str.replace(r'^CC([0-9]{2,})_.*', r'\1', regex=True)`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `str.replace` you could use `str.extract` like this:

```
df['col_name'] = df['col_name'].str.extract(r'^CC(\d+)_')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string = 'CC3309_EasdfewrfwerwxD2Svddserw10_2022'
split = string.split('_')
print(split[0].replace('C',''))
```